# How to fix a VBA "type mismatch" error after switching to 64-bit Excel

Tags: excel, vba, 32bit-64bit

I was using code that was working fine when I was running the 32-bit version of Excel. After I was switched to the 64-Bit version, the macro broke. I updated the dll calls to use `LongPtr` everywhere instead of `Long`.
Is there any way to determine which arguments and return types need to be changed for VBA7, and which don't, for a specific `Declare Function`?

Here is an example of some of the "Declare Functions" that I have updated (there were actually several more too).

```vb
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateDC Lib "gdi32.dll" Alias "CreateDCA" (ByVal lpDriverName As String, ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpOutput As String, lpInitData As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal nWidth As LongPtr, ByVal nHeight As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Const LOGPIXELSY As Long = 90
#Else
    Private Declare CreateDC Lib "gdi32.dll" Alias "CreateDCA" (ByVal lpDriverName As String, ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpOutput As String, lpInitData As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long) As Long
    Private Const LOGPIXELSY As Long = 90
#End If
```

This code was adapted from an answer to this question:
[vb macro string width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012465/vb-macro-string-width-in-pixel)

Relevant snippet is copied here below:

```vb
Private Function GetLabelSize(text As String, font As StdFont) As SIZE
    Dim tempDC As Long
    Dim tempBMP As Long
    Dim f As Long
    Dim lf As LOGFONT
    Dim textSize As SIZE

    tempDC = CreateDC("DISPLAY", vbNullString, vbNullString, ByVal 0)
    tempBMP = CreateCompatibleBitmap(tempDC, 1, 1)
```

I get a runtime error that just says "Compile Error: Type Mismatch." The function call to `CreateDC` is highlighted, and the debugger breaks on the function `GetLabelSize`. I have no idea which variable is now causing the error. I'm also assuming that once I fix this first error, I'll have other errors too.

Do I need to pass the value of that last argument (`ByVal 0`) as an explicitly typed variable? If so how?

Comment: (1) One certain issue is that you have to declare your `tempDC` and `tempBMP` variables similarly via conditional compiler constants  as `LongPtr` or as `Long` (i.e. via `#If VBA7 Then` etc...) (2) Afaik `lpInitData` now is declared `As DEVMODE` referring to a longer `Type` definition and not `As LongPtr`; don't know therefore if `ByVal 0` would be sufficient.

Comment: Further incompatibilities (VBA7): a) `nWidth`/`nHeight` remain `Long` in `Declare PtrSafe Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32" Alias "CreateCompatibleBitmap" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long) As LongPtr` and b) `Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr) As Long` only expects the handle as `LongPtr` :-)

Comment: Thanks @T.M, that did fix my first error.
I edited my question. Based on what I read on this, it seemed like ALL of those 'Declare Functions' would need **LongPtr** instead of **Long**, since I haven't seen anyone say otherwise... Is there a way that I can find which other ones still need type **Long* as arguments? I just tried searching for them individually, but I'm not getting any useful results from MS Docs.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused by what **LongPtr** actually does. According to MS:
"LongPtr is not a true data type because it transforms to a Long in 32-bit environments, or a LongLong in 64-bit environments. Using LongPtr enables writing portable code that can run in both 32-bit and 64-bit environments. Use LongPtr for pointers and handles."

Does that mean that the check for "#If VBA7" isn't needed? That sounds to me like I should have been able to use LongPtr for both 32-bit and 64-bit version.

Comment: *Does that mean that the check for "#If VBA7" isn't needed?* - no, it doesn't. VBA6 does not have `LongPtr` to begin with. You have to use `Long` there, which is not a problem because VBA6 is 32-bit only. *Is there a way that I can find which other ones still need type `Long` as arguments* - yes, there is (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428459/declare-statement-in-win64-vba-office#comment80647569_46428459, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50726918/11683).

Comment: Regarding *"Is there a way that I can find which other ones still need type Long as arguments"*: c.f. also some additional hints and further links at post concerning [API functions (in a UserForm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781069/right-to-left-userforms-in-excel-vba/52806751?r=SearchResults&s=1|42.5952#52806751) @BernoulliLizard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I updated the dll calls to use `LongPtr` everywhere instead of `Long`.

You should have not done that.

By adding `PtrSafe` to a function declaration, you [promise to the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44785205/11683) that you have put `LongPtr` in all places where it needs to be, and nowhere else.

`LongPtr` is a *pointer-sized integer*. It must be used for things that have the same size as a pointer.

To learn which Windows API types should be described as `LongPtr`, you must look at the original function signature, consult https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types, track the used data types through all the `typedef`s down to the basic types, and use `LongPtr` for those that are pointers to things.

For the functions that you have shown, that would be

```vb
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateDC Lib "gdi32.dll" Alias "CreateDCA" (ByVal lpDriverName As String, ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpOutput As String, ByVal lpInitData As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function CreateDC Lib "gdi32.dll" Alias "CreateDCA" (ByVal lpDriverName As String, ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpOutput As String, ByVal lpInitData As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
#End If
```

When you declare variables to hold your `LongPtr` results, you need to use `#If VBA7` too:

```vb
#If VBA7 Then
    Dim tempDC As LongPtr
    Dim tempBMP As LongPtr
#Else
    Dim tempDC As Long
    Dim tempBMP As Long
#End If
```

If you don't have to support [Office 2007 and older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822004/declare-ptrsafe-compatibility-in-excel#comment42222445_26822004), you can ditch the `#If VBA7`s and only use the `LongPtr` branch.

Comment: Helpful in any case! It's your merit to clear up some common misunderstandings (*`M`*) in an easy to understand and better way than I could by simple *comments*. - `M1` *"ALL of those 'Declare Functions' would need LongPtr"*. `M2` *Any* `Long` argument now would become a `LongPtr`*. `M3` *I needn't differentiate between arguments.* `M4` Sort of confusion where LongPtr or `#If VBA7 Then` is needed etc. (not speaking about actually installed Office 64bit vs. 64bit systems).

Comment: Helpful, too [Declaring API functions in 64 bit Office](https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/apideclarations.asp) @GSerg