# Calling asynchronous file write (WriteFileEx) from VBA in Windows?

Tags: vba, asynchronous, kernel32

I am trying to write a stream of data with minimal delay between buffer transfers in VBA. The data may be acquired with maximal 30~35 usec precision in VBA.
But because of continuous data stream, I need to write it in buffered chunks of limited size. So every native VBA write call results in a hundreds msec delay. Since VBA is a one-threaded synchronous envireonment, I loose the input data.

My idea is using the Overlapped write with WriteFileEx, or WriteFile system calls for writing assynchronously. I tried to implement it as below, but failed, because of little experience in converting C notation from manuals to VBA. the hardest part seems submitting there an lpOverlapped struture, because it cannot be directly initialized in VBA the same way as in C. But there may be more obstackes which I do not understand.

Can you please help me to make a working assynchronous WriteFileEx call? Here is my current variant for Excel 2019 32bit, for starter, which does not work as intended.
It writes the data one time, in interlocking IO. I.e. NOT parallel.
And after the program **has finished**, *any* file IO in **Excel** results in **crashing**.

Declarations
`

```
Public Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" _
 (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function CreateFile Lib "kernel32" _
  Alias "CreateFileA" ( _
    ByVal lpFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
    ByVal dwShareMode As Long, _
    lpSecurityAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
    ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
    ByVal hTemplateFile As Long _
) As Long
Public Declare Function WriteFileEx Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal hFile As Long, _
    lpBuffer As Any, _
    ByVal nNumberOfBytesToWrite As Long, _
    lpOverlapped As OVERLAPPED, _
    lpCompletionRoutine As Long _
) As Long
Public Declare Function WriteFile Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal hFile As Long, _
    lpBuffer As Any, _
    ByVal nNumberOfBytesToWrite As Long, _
    lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Long, _
    lpOverlapped As OVERLAPPED _
) As Long

Public Const GENERIC_WRITE As Long = &H40000000
Public Const FILE_SHARE_READ  As Long = &H1
Public Const CREATE_ALWAYS  As Long = &H2
Public Const FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED = &H40000000

Type Long64
    Low As Long
    High As Long
End Type

Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
     nLength As Long   ' Long=4 -> .nLength=14
     lpSecurityDescriptor As Long64 'Long64=8, 
     bInheritHandle As Boolean 'Boolean=2
End Type

Type OVERLAPPED
     Internal As Long
     InternalHigh As Long
     Offset As Long
     OffsetHigh As Long
     hEvent As Long
End Type

`
```

The "program"

```
Dim WAPI32path As String
WAPI32path = "\\.\D:\test.txt"
Dim hFile As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Dummy As Long

Dim SecAtr As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    SecAtr.bInheritHandle = True
    SecAtr.lpSecurityDescriptor.High = &H0
    SecAtr.lpSecurityDescriptor.Low = &H0
    SecAtr.nLength = 14
Dim Overlap As OVERLAPPED
    Overlap.hEvent = &H0
    Overlap.Internal = &H0
    Overlap.InternalHigh = &H0
    Overlap.Offset = &H0
    Overlap.OffsetHigh = &H0

Dim str As String
    str = "agnqevo oapgnfvfrwo!"
For i = 1 To 24
    str = str & vbCrLf & str
Next
hFile = CreateFile(WAPI32path, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, SecAtr, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, &H0)

Debug.Print vbCrLf & "hFile=" & CStr(hFile)
Debug.Print "=====STARTING WRITE OP, LOOK FOR DELAY, THERE SHOULD NTO BE ANY=======" 
DoEvents
Dummy= WriteFileEx(hFile, ByVal StrPtr(str), LenB(str), Overlap, ByVal &H0) 
DoEvents
Debug.Print vbCrLf & "WriteFile=" & Dummy
Debug.Print "=====Shoud have finished in no time====="
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:5")) 'giving it time to flush buffers without checking the Overlap status.
Dummy = CloseHandle(hFile)
Debug.Print vbCrLf & "CloseHandle=" & Dummy
```

When I change WriteFileEx to WriteFile, it does not crash that easily, but still freeses while writing:

```
Dummy = WriteFile(hFile, ByVal StrPtr(str), LenB(str), ByVal &H0, Overlap)
```

Comment: You might be able to get around your timing limitations by moving your code to twinBasic.  https://twinbasic.com/preview.html

Comment: I am using VISA library, which is generally compatible with C/++/#, and VB/VBA.
VBA is convenient for quick UI, fixing algirithms with zero effrot, and putting debug data directly to Excel cells.
I would prefer using Octave, but it has no VISA interface under Windows
The next instrument would be Puthon with PyVISA, which gives little benefits comparing to VBA.
C/++/# are simply not research work tools, requiring too much overhead coding, and harder to modify on demand.
Other languages or environments are not an option.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, making anything paralleled in VBA requires tremendous efforts. I found a way to parallel a routine by copying it to another excel instance, but this method does nto allow passing large arrays of data.

Comment: You may be misunderstanding me.  twinBasic is fully com based and is intended as a replacmeent for VB6/VBA.  You may also be intrested in this post  https://github.com/twinbasic/twinbasic/discussions/867

Comment: Hmm. Ok. And it seems there is a "visual" editor available for quick design. But while I am figuring out how to work with that, do you have an idea how to implement WriteFileEx?

Comment: If I did I would have responded appropriately rather than pointing you at twinBasic.

Comment: A good starting point would be fixing your `declare`s because they are [all wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63801528/11683) in their lack of `LongPtr` where it must be. However, why do you think WriteFile is the bottleneck? How is this writefile code even triggered?

Comment: Well, that is the question, where should which data  type be? For making it compatibld with vba. You see, the code feeds the data to the array with 30usec delay, very stabile.  When dumping the buffer to the ssd that should not be an issue at all. But calling the function creates a large overhead and a delay of hundreds of ms. , which may only be offloaded to a parallel thread. Since normal mulithreading and pointer passing between instances is not available, using WriteEx seems the only option

Comment: P.s. The longPtrs seem as the easiest part. There are obscure data types available only in MS C/net libraries, a thread shared status structure, and a callback. How should I implement these? 

Comment: The difficulty is that I сфт create a file, and get its hadler.  But I could not succeed just simply writing to a file using WriteFileEX, or even simple WriteFile. Any attemp just returns zero. Even synchronous.

Can anyone share a working code with WriteFile() working for x64 platform?

Comment: @freeflow I returned to the problem yesterday and found the bug which prevented it running before: some constants were not declared as public, and Explicit was missing in trial script.

Can you look at it ad guess why is Excel crashing?

Comment: P.S. I made a midification in the style of Dummy= WriteFileEx(hFile, ByVal StrPtr(str), LenB(str), Overlap, AddressOf defsmodule.callback).
The callback function prints something to indicate the end of operation, and closes the handle which I made public.

I discovered that FileWriteEx is not finished after writing all the bytes! And when any other operation, like save the XLSM file is called, it calls back the callback function... and crashes after that!

So what is going on?