# What is the correct VBA declaration for the WinAPI MonitorFromPoint?

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, ms-word, powerpoint

This [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfrompoint) would lead you to think it's this:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function MonitorFromPoint Lib "user32.dll" ( _
                                               POINT As POINTAPI, _
                                               ByVal dwFlags As LongPtr) As Long
```

Along with a UDT:

```
Type POINTAPI
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type
```

But calling this function always returns 0 on 64-bit Office and error 49 "Bad DLL calling convention" on 32-bit Office. FWIW, I left out the conditional compiler VBA7 directive for simplicity.

This appears to work on both 32 and 64 bit Office:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function MonitorFromPoint Lib "user32.dll" ( _
                                               ByVal X As Long, _
                                               ByVal Y As Long, _
                                               ByVal dwFlags As LongPtr) As Long
```

But given the numerous references online (and the Microsoft documentation) using POINTAPI, I don't understand why. Even ChatGPT prefers X & Y but who cares right? ;-)

I also don't understand why the declaration doesn't appear in [this Microsoft documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9970) "Win32API_PtrSafe.TXT"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfrompoint) would lead you to think

Not really, it wouldn't.

`DWORD` [is always](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63801528/11683) `Long`, `HMONITOR` is always `LongPtr`, and the `POINT` structure is accepted by value (`POINT pt`) rather than by reference (`POINT* pt` \ `LPPOINT pt`). VBA's `POINT As POINTAPI` is `ByRef POINT As POINTAPI`.

The correct declaration, however, is tricky, because VBA cannot do byval structs.

For x86 where the arguments are passed on the stack you could simply inline the struct fields:

```vb
Declare PtrSafe Function MonitorFromPoint Lib "user32.dll" ( _
                                               ByVal X As Long, _
                                               ByVal Y As Long, _
                                               ByVal dwFlags As Long) As LongPtr
```

That won't work for x64, because the `POINT` struct is 8 bytes in size, which means it goes into a single register under x64. For that to be doable from VBA, you must declare the function in a way that accepts the entire 8 bytes of the struct as a single integer.
`LongLong` fits the bill, but it does not exist in 32-bit VBA.
`Currency` could also work, provided VBA treats it as an integer, which I'm not sure it does and cannot verify right now.

The cheap and dirty solution therefore is:

```vb
Public Type POINTAPI
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type


#If Win64 Then
    Private Type POINTAPI_AsLongLong
        Value As LongLong
    End Type
    
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function MonitorFromPointInternal _
        Lib "user32.dll" Alias "MonitorFromPoint" ( _
                                                   ByVal pt As LongLong, _
                                                   ByVal dwFlags As Long) As LongPtr
                                                   
    Public Function MonitorFromPoint(pt As POINTAPI, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As LongPtr
        Dim t As POINTAPI_AsLongLong
        LSet t = pt
      
        MonitorFromPoint = MonitorFromPointInternal(t.Value, dwFlags)
    End Function
#Else
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function MonitorFromPointInternal _
        Lib "user32.dll" Alias "MonitorFromPoint" ( _
                                                   ByVal X As Long, _
                                                   ByVal Y As Long, _
                                                   ByVal dwFlags As Long) As LongPtr
    
    Public Function MonitorFromPoint(pt As POINTAPI, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As LongPtr
        MonitorFromPoint = MonitorFromPointInternal(pt.X, pt.Y, dwFlags)
    End Function
#End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing my mind @GSerg. I had tried passing the coords ByVal using a POINTAPI struct and noted the compiler error "User-defined type may not be passed ByVal". Let's see if a GitHub pull request to add a VBA example gets accepted!

Comment: I initially thought this was working but on 64-bit Office, the function always returns 0 if either X or Y is greater than 2!

Comment: @JamieGarroch-MVP You are correct, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Where is the button to flag @GSerg as a genius?! That is a very clever technique and it works on both 32 and 64 bit Office. Thank you so much for the example and explanation, which I suspect goes some way to explaining why this API isn't in the Microsoft PtrSafe document! I was about to fall back to MonitorFromWindow which is a lot easier to use.