# Where to place a Declare statement in a macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've asked ChatGPT about a problem in a VBA macro. Part of its solution was to place this line in the macro: "Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)", but it said to place it before the Sub line. VBA didn't like that location. Where should it go, and how should it be divided into separate lines?

I tried placing the line above the Sub statement, which was the first line of the macro: "Sub MultiSwitch (). But the line was in red, and moved above the macro, under the last line of a preceding macro. I then placed it under the Sub statement, but the line remained red. Breaking the line after "Declare" left all in red, and got a Compile error: "Expected: Sub or Function". Same error when I broke the line in other locations. Here's the code:

```
 Sub MultiSwitch()
' Paul Beverley - Version 31.05.23
' Scripted word/phrase switching


Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

maxWords = 5
myListName = "zzSwitchList"  'etc., etc.
```

Comment: In the VBA ide add a module to your project and put the code at the very top of that new module before and outside of any functions/subs

Comment: `but it said to place it before the Sub line` - that is a correct advice. `VBA didn't like that location` - then that was not the right location, or it was not liked for reasons other than the location. `I tried placing the line above the Sub statement, which was the first line of the macro` - that is the correct location. `and moved above the macro, under the last line of a preceding macro` - does it mean you put it between two subs? Put it before any subs. But before you do that, note that this declaration is completely wrong and you should not use it to begin with. ChatGPT produces garbage.

Answer (score -1):

place the **TOP** of a module or a class module, just like @NickSlash and @GSerg said before. Like this:

Please refer to this [Declare statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/declare-statement) for further.

```vb
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
rem >@GSerg said: Please see <https://stackoverflow.com/a/63801528/11683>. The parameter dwMilliseconds must be declared As Long regardless of 64 or 32 bit. The reason why "both of them are error-free" is that under the x86 calling convention your LongPtr resolves to Long, which is the correct data type in the first place, and under the x64 calling convention this parameter is passed in the register rather than on the stack, and the register is big enough to accommodate the 64 bits the LongPtr resolves to, so no stack misalignment occurs. This code happens to work, as opposed to being correct. 


Sub ...
End sub

'... ' if there are other Subs
 

 Sub MultiSwitch()
' Paul Beverley - Version 31.05.23
' Scripted word/phrase switching

maxWords = 5
myListName = "zzSwitchList"  'etc., etc.
```

> @GSerg said: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63801528/11683. The parameter dwMilliseconds must be declared As Long regardless of 64 or 32 bit. The reason why "both of them are error-free" is that under the x86 calling convention your LongPtr resolves to Long, which is the correct data type in the first place, and under the x64 calling convention this parameter is passed in the register rather than on the stack, and the register is big enough to accommodate the 64 bits the LongPtr resolves to, so no stack misalignment occurs. This code happens to work, as opposed to being correct.

[image]

Comment: Like I mentioned, the declaration itself is wrong. Please do not advise it. The correct signature is `ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long`.

Comment: @GSerg NO, when I compile the code and run it to test, both of them are error-free. Cause the declaration has PtrSafe it is applied to the 64-bit version of Word, and the parameter also has to be the LongPtr instead of Long, Long is applied to the 32-bit version though.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63801528/11683. The parameter `dwMilliseconds` must be declared `As Long` regardless of 64 or 32 bit. The reason why "both of them are error-free" is that under the x86 calling convention your `LongPtr` resolves to `Long`, which is the correct data type in the first place, and under the x64 calling convention this parameter is passed in the register rather than on the stack, and the register is big enough to accommodate the 64 bits the `LongPtr` resolves to, so no stack misalignment occurs. This code *happens to work*, as opposed to being correct.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you very much. Just because I have no problem compiling and implementing it, I will add your comments to the comments of my source code just in case. I think it is because I am an ignorant and inexperienced person,  so I will reserve your valuable comments first, just in case I need them in the future.